# How to replace a pattern in a string in bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have the following strings stored in variables in shell

```
a1="aaa,bbb3,12,ccc,"
a2="aaa,2,bbb,ccc,"
```

I want to execute a common command on the above string variables to remove the object number from the path. an object number is a number between 2 commas.

So the result should be

```
a1="aaa,bbb3,ccc,"
a2="aaa,bbb,ccc,"
```

How I can do that?

I tried:

```
echo ${a1//,[0-9],/,} ==> wrong result
echo ${a2//,[0-9],/,} ==> good result
```

---

Also I have the following strings stored in variables in shell

```
a1="aaa,bbb3,#zu_45,ccc,"
a2="aaa,#mn,bbb,ccc,"
a3="aaa,bbb,ccc,#kn,"
```

And I want to execute a common command on the above string variables to remove the object which start with `#` from the path. an object located between 2 commas.

So the result should be

```
a1="aaa,bbb3,ccc,"
a2="aaa,bbb,ccc,"
a3="aaa,bbb,ccc,"
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this sed:

```
sed -r 's/,(#.*)?[0-9]+//' file

a1="aaa,bbb3,ccc,"
a2="aaa,bbb,ccc,"
a3="aaa,bbb,ccc,"
```

Comment: What other pattern do you want? Isn't this giving you your expected result?

Comment: It worked on your given input text. Can you provide an input that doesn't work.

Comment: It might be worth specifying which implementation of `sed` it's being tested with. GNU sed, for instance, is quite different from the BSD sed shipped by Apple and others.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, you can use `extglob` for this.

```
$ a1="aaa,bbb3,12,ccc,"
$ a2="aaa,2,bbb,ccc,"
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo "${a1//,+([0-9]),/,}"
aaa,bbb3,ccc,
$ echo "${a2//,+([0-9]),/,}"
aaa,bbb,ccc,
$
```

It's well documented in [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#line-77) and many other places.

---

For your second question, you can handle this either with more advanced pattern matching, or by treating the comma-separated elements as fields and processing them individually.

First, a pattern match solution.

```
$ a1="aaa,bbb3,#zu_45,ccc,"
$ a2="aaa,#mn,bbb,ccc,"
$ a3="aaa,bbb,ccc,#kn,"
$ echo "${a1//,#+([^,]),/,}"
aaa,bbb3,ccc,
$ echo "${a2//,#+([^,]),/,}"
aaa,bbb,ccc,
$ echo "${a3//,#+([^,]),/,}"
aaa,bbb,ccc,
$
```

(I'll just point out for any wandering readers that while patterns like this may *look* like regular expressions, [they are not](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46436/13377).)

Second, a solution that treats fields like fields would of course involve a loop. Here's an example as a one-liner:

```sh
$ a=(${a1//,/ }); unset newa; for i in "${a[@]}"; do if [[ ! $i =~ ^# ]]; then newa="$newa${newa:+,}$i"; fi; done; echo "$newa"
aaa,bbb3,ccc
```

You can repeat this for the other variables.

Note that this depends on your data not having any spaces in it, since that's the character used to separate fields in a bash array.

Comment: ...and for the second one, `${a1//,#*([^,]),/,}` would do. I think that `extglob` is a cleaner solution than bash regexes, so +1 from me.

Comment: Tom, thanks, I had the same thought, I just took a little longer to add it to the answer.  :-)

Comment: The one-liner at the end is rather evil, conflating whitespace with separators (making `foo,bar baz,qux` the same as `foo,bar,baz,qux`). I'd think that setting IFS to `,` would be a saner approach. The extglob approach is great, though, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure bash, you can do:

```
$ re='(.*),[0-9]+,(.*)'
$ a1="aaa,bbb3,12,ccc,"
$ a2="aaa,2,bbb,ccc,"
$ [[ $a1 =~ $re ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]},${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
aaa,bbb3,ccc,
$ [[ $a2 =~ $re ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]},${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
aaa,bbb,ccc,
```

Those `echo`s could be turned into assignments, giving you what you wanted.

Rather than doing a search and replace, you can just capture the parts before and after using `( )` and they will be stored in the special array variable `$BASH_REMATCH`.

For the second one, you could do something similar:

```
$ re='(.*),#[^,]*,(.*)'
$ a1="aaa,bbb3,#zu_45,ccc,"
$ a2="aaa,#mn,bbb,ccc,"
$ a3="aaa,bbb,ccc,#kn,"
$ [[ $a1 =~ $re ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]},${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
aaa,bbb3,ccc,
$ [[ $a2 =~ $re ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]},${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
aaa,bbb,ccc,
$ [[ $a3 =~ $re ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]},${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
aaa,bbb,ccc,
```

Using a `[^,]` (not a comma) character class ensures that the rest of the string isn't consumed.

#### update

You could turn this into a function like this:

```
$ rm_hash () { 
>     local re='(.*),#[^,]*,(.*)'
>     local subject="$1"
>     [[ $subject =~ $re ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]},${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
> }
$ a1="aaa,bbb3,#zu_45,ccc,"
$ rm_hash $a1
aaa,bbb3,ccc,
```

Answer (score 0):

A bash only solution:

> ... remove the object number from the path ...

```
$ a1="aaa,bbb3,12,ccc,"
$ echo ${a1//,+([0-9]),/,}
aaa,bbb3,ccc,
```

> ... remove the object which start with # from the path ...

```
$ a1="aaa,bbb3,#zu_45,ccc,"
$ echo ${a1//,#*([^,]),/,}
aaa,bbb3,ccc,
```

The above two solutions can be combined into a single operation:

```
$ a1="aaa,32,bbb3,#zu_45,ccc,"
$ echo ${a1//,@(#*([^,])|+([0-9])),/,}
aaa,bbb3,ccc,
```

All of these solutions rely on [shell option](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options) `extglob` being set. They use [bash extended patterns](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language) to match parts of the string:

- `+([0-9])` - Matches one or more digits;
- `#*([^,])` - Matches any string that starts with a hash [`#`] and is followed by any number of not-commas;
- `@(...|...)` - Matches exactly *one* of the given patterns, which are separated by the pipe-symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a one-liner, but a bullet-proof method:

```
IFS=, read -d '' -ra ary <<< "$variable"
unset ary[${#ary[@]}-1]
```

will create an array `ary`, the fields of which are the fields in your variable `variable` (fields are comma-separated). Then, if you want to remove all the numbers:

```
for i in "${!ary[@]}"; do
    [[ ${ary[i]} = +([[:digit:]]) ]] && unset ary[$i]
done
```

or to remove all the elements that start with a hash:

```
for i in "${!ary[@]}"; do
    [[ ${ary[i]} = \#* ]] && unset ary[$i]
done
```

Finally, to put that back into your variable:

```
printf -v variable '%s,' "${ary[@]}"
```

A function that does that:

```
remove_number() {
    local ary i
    IFS=, read -d '' -ra ary <<< "${!1}"
    unset ary[${#ary[@]}-1]
    for i in "${!ary[@]}"; do
        [[ ${ary[i]} = +([[:digit:]]) ]] && unset ary[$i]
    done
    printf -v "$1" '%s,' "${ary[@]}"
}
```

Demo (assuming this function is defined in session):

```
$ a1="aaa,bbb3,12,ccc,"
$ remove_number a1
$ echo "$a1"
aaa,bbb3,ccc,
```

This also works if there are newlines in variable (notice: it doesn't remove the negative number... that was not really clear from your requirements, but it's rather trivial to modify the function to also handle this, see `is_number` below):

```
$ a=$'aaa,\n\nnewline here\n,123456,-1234,abc\n,'
$ echo "$a"
aaa,

newline here
,123456,-1234,abc
,
$ remove_number a
$ echo "$a"
aaa,

newline here
,-1234,abc
,
```

Oh, and it works if the number appears in the first field (unlike some other answers):

```
$ a='1234,abc,'
$ b='1234,'
$ remove_number a
$ remove_number b
$ echo "a='$a'"; echo "b='$b'"
a='abc,'
b=','
```

Also fine for "empty" lists:

```
$ a=','
$ remove_number a
$ echo "$a"
,
```

A more functional approach: make a function that removes a field if a condition, given by a function, is met:

```
remove_cond() {
    # $1 is condition
    # $2 is name of variable that contains list
    local ary i
    IFS=, read -d '' -ra ary <<< "${!2}"
    unset ary[${#ary[@]}-1]
    for i in "${!ary[@]}"; do
        "$1" "${ary[i]}" && unset ary[$i]
    done
    printf -v "$2" '%s,' "${ary[@]}"
}
```

Then a couple of conditions:

```
is_number() {
    [[ $1 = ?(-)+([[:digit:]]) ]]
}
is_bang() {
    [[ $1 = \#* ]]
}
is_bang_or_number() {
    is_number "$1" || is_bang "$1"
}
```

With these set in current session:

```
$ a="aaa,bbb3,#zu_45,ccc,"
$ remove_cond is_bang a
$ echo "$a"
aaa,bbb3,ccc,
$ a='1234,#lol,keep me please,-1234,'
$ remove_cond is_bang_or_number a
$ echo "$a"
keep me please,
```